# How to use populate in node js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have to populate students in my data,

```
"attendances" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5851702b9accfc6e70d55107"),
        "students" : [ 
            {
                "student" : ObjectId("5850e6d596d4de3c1f4a0614"),
                "_id" : ObjectId("5851702b9accfc6e70d55109"),
                "ispresent" : "No"
            },  }]
```

My schema,

```
 attendances: [{
date: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
},
created_by: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Employee'
},
students: [{
    student: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Student'
    },
    ispresent: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    }
}]
```

}],

```
 Attendance.findById(id).populate('attendances.students')
```

I tried the above way but fails.Can any one please suggest help.Thanks.

Comment: Would you put down your mongoose schema and edit the well-formatted JSON of what you're expecting from mongoose with population?

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your population predicate by the **dot notation** while you're digging deeper into both **object** or **array** to refer at the end to another valid schema of type `Schema.Types.ObjectId`, so according to your mentioned schema, you query would be as follow:

```
 Attendance.findById(id).populate('attendances.students.student')
```